# RegEx to select part of match

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using gvim to edit a document. An excerpt of the document is:

```
ST*123*foo
WIL*ST*bar
Z91*R*Station
```

Using regex, I'd like to select `ST` in the second line, where it exists between two `*` (and is not at the start of a line), so I can highlight it a specific color.

I thought `\*ST\*` might work, but it selects the `*`s, which I don't want. I've also tried (to no avail) a few variations of `{}` in an attempt to select x characters from my selection.

Comment: This selects the `*` characters which is undesired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a lookahead and a lookbehind assertion:

```
/\v(\*)@<=ST(\*)@=
```

**Details:**

- `\v`: Very magic to avoid excessive escaping
- `(\*)@<=`: Lookbehind to assert that we have `*` behind
- `ST`: Match `ST`:
- `(\*)@=`: Lookahead to assert that we have `*` ahead

Comment: Using `\zs` & `\ze` can often make this easier. `/\*\zsST\ze\*`. See `:h /\zs`

Comment: Thanks @PeterRincker, I didn't know about `/\zs`